# how to find length in R for json

Tags: r

how can I get the length ?

this is json , when i print, it gives me output  like-:

```
print(a) 
[[1]]
[[0.5],[43]] 

dput(a)
list(structure("[[0.5],[43]]", class = "json"))
```

if I use `length(a)` it gives 1

ans should be 2

please tell me how can i do that??

Comment: That’s not an R list. Square brackets are indexing operators.

Comment: If you can get the `dput(a)` and update it, would appreicate it.  I can't understand the structure of your data

Comment: yea , updated again

Comment: Not sure why you're saying the class of `a` is list, when in your structure it says it's a json object. Maybe you need to parse the json, such as with `jsonlite::fromJSON`. This is an example of why having the *exact* type of data you're working with is necessary for folks to help debug

Comment: Perhaps you need to also load a package wit a library() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lengths` to get the length of each of the elements

```
lengths(a)
#[1] 2
```

---

Or another option is to loop through the `list` with one of the apply family functions (`lapply/sapply/vapply`) and use `length`

```
sapply(a, length)
```

But, this would be slower compared to `lengths`

Also, if the `list` is of `length` 1, then extract the `list` and apply `length`

```
length(a[[1]])
```

#### Update

The OP's `list` element is `json`, so we can use

```
library(jsonlite)
nrow(fromJSON(a[[1]]))
#[1] 2
```

For multiple `list` elements, loop through the `list` with `sapply`

```
sapply(a, function(x) nrow(fromJSON(x)))
```

#### data

```
a <- list(c(0.5, 43))
```

Comment: hey , thanks check my question , i updated it , still it gives me 1

Comment: @jony Are you using the data in my post or the one i showed from `python` list.  `python` list works only in python

Comment: this list i created in R

Comment: @jony What about `[[0.5],[43]]` ?

Comment: that's what i got , when i print `a`  but when i use `length(a)` or `lengths(a)` it gives 1

Comment: @jony You meant `a <- list(c(0.5, 43)); lengths(a)` is 1?.  The `list` you created I am not sure about the structure of it.  Is it a string.  Please use `dput(a)` and also if you used any other packages in creating the `list`

Comment: no that is 2 , see question i updated , when `print(a)` what i got , i am passing that a into `length(a)` or `lengths(a)` it gives me 1

Comment: `dput(a)` is `list(structure("[[0.5],[43]]", class = "json"))`

Comment: @jony so, it is a `json`,that info was not in the post?

Answer (score 0):

In general functions can be applied to lists using `lapply` or `sapply`. In this case you would call

```
lapply(a, length)
```

Which produced element-wise lengths as a new list. To get a vector you can use `sapply`

```
sapply(a, length)
```

Comment: hey , thanks check my question , i updated it , this is not working